# Vivado HW manager does not detect my ARTY A7

Tags: fpga, vivado

I installed Vivado(2022.2) ML Standard with all the drivers on Windows 10. As I try to auto or manual connect ARTY A7 in Vivado hardware manager the device doesen't show up.

### What I tried:

- Changed USB cable,
- Connect device to other PC, where it is working!,
- Reinstalling vivado,
- Reinstalling cable drivers by running *install_drivers_wrapper.bat* in vivado installation file *nt64*,
- Reinstalling cable drivers by the following [instructions](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/1013230?language=en_US) *I know they are for windows 7, but that was out of despair*

### What I found:

It is stil not working, but in my device manager I only see **USB Serial Converter B**, but as I was reading and saw on othaer computer where it is working, there were **USB Serial Converter A and B**.

Thanks for all the help in advaced.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it is working now. I installed [adept](https://digilent.com/reference/software/adept/start?redirect=2#software_downloads) and it detected my device and after that Vivado hardware manager detects it too.

Comment: Thanks for joining SO! just be aware this is more a place for programming questions, the 'super user' stack is a better place for these types of questions https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4836/what-is-the-difference-between-super-user-and-stack-overflow